# whenever i update my table i want to store my old data(old-row) in a new table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER items_
ON test 
after update
AS
begin
    INSERT INTO test2(id,namecan)
    SELECT id,namecan from test
end
```

I Have tried with trigger but i didnt get any results so please help me how to deal with it
methods involving two stored procedures are also welcome

Comment: what is the new and old data ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a stored procedure, but I would use a trigger.

With a stored procedure, I'd perceive you using a cursor on the otherDatabase table to read through the records and compare each with the values in Table1 to determine whether Table1's data needed to be written to Table2, and if so, to do it.

With a trigger, I would simply update the data in Table1 by whatever means, without concerning myself with what the overwriting data is, and in the trigger,

use the old and new values using the ##Inserted & ##Deleted (system) tables to determine if the old values (##Deleted) needed to be written to Table2.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger syntax is wrong

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER items_ after update
ON test 
for each row 
begin
    INSERT INTO test2(id,namecan) values (old.id,old.namecan);
end; //
delimiter ;
```

So this trigger will make an entry to the test2 table every time you update row in the test table with the old row values from test table.

Answer (score 0):

If you don want to use triggers, you can go for this concept..
Let there is a form from which you are inserting the values on a table say **register** table. And the action of the form in going to servlet **MyServlet**. In **Myservlet**
you can first fetch the data from the **Register** table and store it into the **Rsultset** object let ***rs***. And after that insert the ***rs*** into a new table.
Please let me know if m not clear to u..

Answer (score 0):

You should call old.id and old.namecan (i assume that table 'test' have 'id' and 'namecan' field)to get the older data. your trigger body should look like this

```
begin
    INSERT INTO test2(id,namecan) value(old.id, old.namecan)
end
```

'old' will reference to record which you update.